# Proper method of creating 3 dimmensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I want to create an array that looks like this in php:

```
_________________________________________
|time | event | childEvents              |
|_____|_______|__________________________|
|9:00 |Event1 | String[]{subE11, subE12} |
|_____|_______|__________________________|
|10:00|Event2 | String[]{subE21, subE22} |
|_____|_______|__________________________|
```

There will be more rows, but this is just a sample. So pretty much I need to have a String Array as one of the elements in the array. I am just assuming(could be wrong) that the best/only way to do this is with a 3-dimensional array.

```
$stuff = array(
    array('time' => '9:00 AM', 'event' => 'Event1', childEvents => (array(subE11, subE12)),
    array('time' => '2:00 AM', 'event' => 'Event2', childEvents => (array(subE21, subE22)),

); //I get error here
```

In the commented line, I get the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'`
I need to pass this array as a JSON. I can pass three dimensional array to json using
 `echo json_encode($stuff);` Am I doing something wrong initializing my array?

Comment: 1) Count the braces: in the two middle lines you have 3 opening but 2 closing only. 2) `childEvents` must be quoted.

Comment: Your missing a couple `)`

Comment: Try this `array('time' => '9:00 AM', 'event' => 'Event1', 'childEvents' => array('subE11', 'subE12')),`

Comment: I feel really stupid now. I just forgot some parenthesis. +1 to everyone who caught my mistake.

Comment: @MarcellFulop You were the first to catch my mistake. If you put it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Count the braces: in the two middle lines you have 3 opening but 2 closing only.

2) `childEvents` must be quoted as well as its values:

```
$stuff = array(
    array('time' => '9:00 AM', 'event' => 'Event1', 'childEvents' => (array('subE11', 'subE12'))),
    array('time' => '2:00 AM', 'event' => 'Event2', 'childEvents' => (array('subE21', 'subE22')))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were ***kind of*** close. Try this:

```
$stuff = array(
    array('time' => '9:00 AM', 'event' => 'Event1', 'childEvents' => array('subE11', 'subE12')),
    array('time' => '2:00 AM', 'event' => 'Event2', 'childEvents' => array('subE21', 'subE22')),
);
```

[Codepad exampl](http://codepad.org/L1YRE5Ih)e w/ var_dump.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stuff = array(
    array('time' => '9:00 AM', 'event' => 'Event1', 'childEvents' => (array('subE11', 'subE12'))),
    array('time' => '2:00 AM', 'event' => 'Event2', 'childEvents' => (array('subE21', 'subE22')))
);
```

Remove extra `comma` at the last of 2nd array and add `single quotes` for `childEvents` key and their values.

Answer (score -2):

Here another example that will help you how to define properly

```
<?php   
 $categories = array( array ( array( 'CAR_TIR', 'Tires', 100 ),
                   array( 'CAR_OIL', 'Oil', 10 ),
                   array( 'CAR_SPK', 'Spark Plugs', 4 )
                  ),
               array ( array( 'VAN_TIR', 'Tires', 120 ),
                   array( 'VAN_OIL', 'Oil', 12 ),
                   array( 'VAN_SPK', 'Spark Plugs', 5 )
                  ),
               array ( array( 'TRK_TIR', 'Tires', 150 ),
                   array( 'TRK_OIL', 'Oil', 15 ),
                   array( 'TRK_SPK', 'Spark Plugs', 6 )
                  )
              );
?>
```

Comment: @usmanallam, thank you for your addition to the question - another example.  However this does not answer the OP's question and I will Recommend Deletion.